# Stop running handler with postdelay (Android)

Tags: android

I created a notification to be fired with a delay, done with Handler.postdelay

Now I want my user to be able to stop the running handler process somewhere between those 30 seconds:

```
 handler.postDelayed(new Runnable () {
        public void run() {
            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(Inlopen.this)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.iconsmall)
                            .setContentTitle("U moet uw voeten controleren!")
                            .setContentText("Uw moet uw voeten controleren!");
            Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            mBuilder.setSound(alarmSound);
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());

        }
    }, 30000 );
```

How to do this?
I already searched a lot, but I couldn't find out how to do it with this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Handler.removeCallbacks(Runnable)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacks(java.lang.Runnable)). The best option would be to create a constant Runnable object and provide it when using [Handler.postDelayed(Runnable, long)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)) as you will then be able to remove said Runnable specifically from the queue.

```
// create the Runnable object
private final static Runnable NOTIF = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO notification code goes here...
    };

};

// then use it
handler.removeCallbacks(NOTIF); // to remove any posts of NOTIF
handler.postDelayed(NOTIF, 30000); // to post NOTIF with a delay of 30 seconds
```

Comment: where do I have to place this?

Comment: Put the Runnable along with your other variables. The calls themselves can happen wherever you want, as longs as the handler is ready to rock and/or roll.

Comment: Thanks! Managed to get it work with help of your code!

Answer (score 0):

you have to call `handler.removeCallbacks(null)`. This way all the queued runnbable will be removed